# Importing mongodb.ts in TypeScript file

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to import the code inside this file in my TypeScript app:

http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fe3bc0bfce1f#samples%2fimageboard%2fmongodb.ts

However, when I try to compile this file, there is no output js file generated nor do I get any warnings.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are compiling a declarations file which contains only types used by Typescript. `Mongodb.ts` is used as a a representative for the `javascript` code that will take care of the connection to mongodb. The intention here clearly is to use `mongodb.ts` as a stub in order for the compiler to be able to typecheck code that uses mongodb. In your code, you have to load `mongodb.ts` as an external module and then program against it. At runtime, for instance in `nodejs`, a different module that contains the "productive" javascript code will be loaded. As an example, you can use the following code in your app:

**myapp.ts**

```
import mongodb = module("mongodb");
var server = new mongodb.Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true}, {})
var db = new mongodb.Db('mydb', server);
```

This is taken from one of the examples at codeplex. Once again, in order to run this you need to have a runtime environment that provides an implementation of mongodb.

Comment: thanks, my bad. the mongodb driver was not installed for nodejs. that solved the problem